# A confusion about scopes of If Else statements in python

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement

```
def numbers_def(n):
    #######if-1#######
    if n <= 1:
        print('0 and 1 is special numbers')
        return False
    ######end of if-1######

    for x in range(2, n):
        ########if-2#######
        if n % x == 0:
            print('({}) = ({}) X ({})'.format(n, x, x))
            return False
        #####end of if-2#####


    #######else-1######
    else:
        print('({}) is a prime number'.format(n))
        return True

for x in range(0, 20):
    numbers_def(x)
```

This is a simple Python program to find the prime numbers between 0 to 20, that i found in a video tutorial. In above program `if-1` start's in line number 2, and stop in line number 6. 
`if-2` is in side of the `for loop`
And there is a `else-1` which is not belongs to any of the above `if` statements. If it was belongs to `if-1` it should generate the following output when the parameter n is equal to 4

```
4 = 2 X 2 
4 is a prime number
```

How does that `else-1` act for this program? What is the purpose of using `return boolean` values?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `else` statement belongs to the `for` loop and not to any `if` condition.

Its meaning is "*no break*". When the `for` loop does not end with a `break`, i.e. when all items are exhausted then and only then is the else suite executed.

The idiom is this:

```
for n in sequence:
    if is_ok(n):
        print("found")
        break
else:
    # no break
    print("not found")
```

---

Your program does not make a real use of the for-else construct, anyway it is there.